# Sequentially concatenate multiple ogg vorbis files into a single file with .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, ogg, oggvorbis

Assuming I have multiple .ogg files which I need to combine sequentially into a single file, can anyone recommend a library or some code for doing so using .NET?  Also assume they all have the same number of channels.

I found some reference to using the "copy /b" command from the command line, but this seams to combine them "vertically", the duration of the new file does not equal the sum of the combined files.

Thanks

Comment: I think binary concatenation only works if the stream IDs differ(which is usually the case). But not sure how good the player support is for this kind of file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google "[oggcat windows"](http://www.google.com/search?q=oggcat%20windows) for a [command line tool](http://en.flossmanuals.net/ogg-theora/ch052_cat-files) which you should be able to call from your app.

Comment: this worked well.  I will leave this question open another day or 2 to see if anyone can present a .NET code solution.

BTW, here is the link to the tool, took me a little bit to find it.

http://dev.streamnik.de/files.html

Comment: @bulltorious: You should then upvote this answer. OK, I do it for you